# SimpleHTTPserver outside network unaccesible

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I've set up a simple http server on kali linux listening on port 8000 with the command:
`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

I've tested the server from my phone (which is connected to the same network) by putting: `192.168.1.59:8000` on my web browser.
It works perfectly.

Problem occurs when I try to access it from outside the network. I've opened port 8000 on my router for both UDP and TCP for the IPv4 of `192.168.1.59`. When I get my public IP address and search it the same way I did before `mypublicIP:8000` it outputs the error of:
***ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT***

After doing some digging I read that the problem may be my firewall (which I had none installed at the time). So I installed ufw with `apt-get install ufw`. And allowed port 8000 `ufw allow 8000`. But it still gives me the same problem!

I did an nmap scan to my public IP, and it showed me the following: `8000/tcp filtered http-alt`. Shouldn't is show opened? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to access the service via your public IP, from within the internal network? Try accessing it from another network (i.e: cellular or a friend's house), or using a service like https://canyouseeme.org/. I suspect that this is a [Hairpin NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) issue with your router. Many consumer routers do not support this, so you'll need to use the host's internal IP when inside the network, and your external IP when outside.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a Hairpin NAT issue with my router. Many consumer routers do not support this, so I had to use the host's internal IP when inside the network, and my external IP when outside.

Credit to @Attie

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Web Server such as Apache2 or Nginx? Please install a Web Server and then try to access it from outside your network. If you do so, it might work.

**Note:** You should do some security tips to make your Web Server safer. For example, if  you've installed Apache2, open its main config file, and add the following lines to it:

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

The lines above will disallow Apache to show its version, what OS you're using, etc.

I hope my answer will help you